# how to implement one google-service.json file in to multiple android project

Tags: android, .net, cordova, ionic3, phonegap

I working on a project that develops android .apk files using phone gap.
I use different them to manage my mobile app or when it builds the app I've changed its package id in my repo. I want to use push notification in all my generated apps. I can't manually add every time google-service.json in my repo or not wan go again and again on google console to add a new project with Package Id.

Comment: Firebase allows only one google-service.json file for each Bundle ID. So you should add new Bundle ID to Firebase and it will provide a different google-service.json for you.

Comment: Is there any way to add new Bundle ID using API and get the google-service.json file using API?

Comment: I dont think there is any API like this to add new Bundle Id to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You should download each play-services.json files from each project and when you build your project you should add a script or a task to swap between the files.

Comment: my project build apk automatically I can't add paly service.json manually in it. Is there any to get the google-service.json file using API.